# sqlalchemy: add_ inside outerjoin does not apply aliases

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to filter inactive elements in my sqlalchemy queries.

I'm able to use a filter to do it for easy queries but when I have joins in relationships filter is not returning results if one of the relationships does not exist.

I saw some solutions, like generating the left side expression but I have a generic function used in all my models and I was not able to create it.

An option is to add this filter in the relationship model but I would like to avoid it because is not a global filter, it only applies in some situations.

I want to add the filter inside the join clause to have results although the relationship does not have any entry.

**The SQL I would like to create is:**

```
SELECT *
FROM customers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN distributors AS distributors_1 ON distributors_1.id = customers.distributor_id AND distributors_1._active IS true
WHERE customers.distributor_id = 1 AND customers._active IS true
```

Using sqlachemy I'm trying to create the query based on the models because is parametrized.

**Current model:**

```
class Customer(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    _active = Column(Boolean(1), default=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    distributor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('distributors.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    distributor = relationship("Distributor", lazy="noload")

class Distributor(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'distributors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    _active = Column(Boolean(1), default=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    customers = relationship("Customer", lazy="noload")
```

**Query generation:**

```
model = Customer
relationship = "distributor"
rel_model = getattr(model, relationship) --> *Customer.distributor*
alias = aliased(relationship)

query.outerjoin(alias, and_(rel_model, getattr(alias, "_active").is_(True)))
options = contains_eager(rel_model, alias=alias)
query = query.options(options)
```

Doing that the sqlalchemy is not creating the right aliases in the query, having the following sql as result, which is not a valid sql:

```
    SELECT *
        FROM customers 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN distributors AS distributors_1 ON **distributors.id** = customers.distributor_id AND distributors_1._active IS true
        WHERE customers.distributor_id = 1 AND customers._active IS true

--> Unknown column 'distributors.id' in 'on clause'
```

As you can see is generated *distributors.id* instead of the alias *distributors_1.id*

Without using the add_ function the aliases is working properly and generating a valid SQL.

**Problem hypothesis**

I think the problem is with the *rel_model* variable, is not able to convert *Customer.distributor* to the aliased version because is inside the and_ function

Using the *and_* function inside the *outerjoin* is not applying the aliases in the add_ expression.

I can't write the outerjoin left expression because my function is generic and I can't know which is the column used in the relationship.

I can't convert the *rel_model* variable because I don't know which is the column used in the relationship.

There are a way to generate the left expression from the sqlalchemy model? for example recovering the column used in the relationship?

Can I use the add_ function in a way where outerjoin is adding the aliases correctly in the sql sentence?

Comment: It seems strange that `getattr(model, "_active").is_(True)` would produce `distributors_1._active IS true`, given that `model = Customer`. There's a bunch of variables without clear definitions, so this is not a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @ilja-everilä!

I updated the problem description, apologize for the missing information. I hope the problem will be a bit more clear.

`getattr(model, "_active").is_(True)` is generated correctly.

The problem is with `getattr(model, relationship)` in the `_add` function inside the `outerjoin`